# UnhandledAlertException doesn't catch alert exception

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

please check on this snippet:

```
try {
      myTransactionsPage.getEnterTransaction();

    } catch (UnhandledAlertException e) {
        String alertText = e.getAlertText();
        assertThat(alertText.contains("Please enter text"));
    }
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

I want to make an assertion about alert text. When I press 'add transaction' key (which is simple .click()) i want to catch an unhandleAlertException. Which is so surprising i get

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Please enter text in the Paid To/From input box.}
```

Have you encountered this problem? Catching an exception doesn't catch it?

Comment: How are you `press 'add transaction' key` within your code?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have handled alert exception,

```
  try {
    //click button
  } catch (UnhandledAlertException e) {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      assertThat(alertText.contains("Please enter text"));
      alert.accept();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` is thrown when you do not deal with the alert box.

It is not possible to take screenshot with the alert box using selenium. Either you need to accept or decline the alert box.

In my scenario, I accept the alert box and take the screenshot of the URL.

```
try {
   //capture the screenshot   
  } catch (UnexpectedAlertPresentException e) {
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    String alertText = alert.getText();
    System.out.println("ERROR: (ALERT BOX DETECTED) - ALERT MSG : " + alertText);
    alert.accept();
}
```